# cURL error 60 in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, ssl, curl, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.4 and when trying to authenticate using FB login i am getting this error 
RequestException in CurlFactory.php line 187:
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

I have tried by adding the cacert.pem file to C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem and adding the path in php.ini as curl.cainfo="C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
But still it is getting the same error. 
Please help..

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858351/php-ssl-certificate-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate/32095378#32095378

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - SSL certificate error: unable to get local issuer certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858351/php-ssl-certificate-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)